# Triggering VS Code python debugger on request

Tags: python, django, debugging, visual-studio-code, request

I need to trigger VS Code debugger on entry point whenever I hit some route in Django. Meaning, I need to start the debugger whenever I click on some link in my local Django app that starts its execution so that I could step through the whole particular request life cycle.

I only know how to start debugger when the debugger itself starts script execution but I couldn't find any answers to the aforementioned scenario. And if it's not possible using VS Code debugger, maybe there's another tool that could help me with that?

Comment: Have you tried Python's built-in debugger? https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pdb.html

Comment: I finally managed to make PyCharm debugger trigger on request. Turned out I forgot to specify working directory in my debug configuration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use Pycharm for this.(This works in both `Pycharm community` and `Pycharm Professional`) I'm not sure if there is such option in VS Code.

You need to follow these steps for that.

1. Add a Run configuration for your Django project in Pycharm. Locate the `manage.py` script in it. Add parameters as `runserver` to that.
2. Put a `breakpoint` at the beginning of your view which is called when the endpoint is hit.
3. Click on the debug button which is right to the `run configuration` which will start your server in `debug` mode.

[image]

4. When you hit the endpoint from your browser, it should stop the execution where you mentioned the breakpoint in `Pycharm`.

Comment: I tried it but still no luck triggering debugger from a Django endpoint. What could be the issue?

Comment: You should run the server in debug mode

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. I click the debug button and my settings.py file has DEBUG = True

Comment: The fun part is that it should work. I do exactly what's shown in the video: https://youtu.be/zFuaU3Sl4-c

Comment: did you setup the debug point on where you want to stop before running in debug mode

Comment: are you choosing the right RunConfiguration that you've created before clicking on debug button?

Comment: Idk, looks good to me: https://justpaste.it/2c8v5
I tried both.

Comment: In your case, you should choose `manage` from the drop down. And make sure you're using the right `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`.

Comment: I have the same exact value set in my manage.py. I added a screenshot for the above link.

Comment: If there is no other choice, you can try the built-in `breakpoint()` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint